# Code refactor : replace model with repository

Tags: magento2, cms, admin-controller, tests

I am trying to refactor code of `app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Page/Delete.php` by replacing `\Magento\Cms\Model\Page` with `\Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface` and **removing direct use of objectManager** by introducing `dependency injection`.

But now I am seeing following error in Travis-CI report

Error: Call to a member function getTitle() on null

How can I fix this? 
What changes need to be done in the test class?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to modify file `vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Page/Delete.php`
from

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Page;

class Delete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Cms::page_delete';

    /**
     * Delete action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // check if we know what should be deleted
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id');
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($id) {
            $title = "";
            try {
                // init model and delete
                $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Cms\Model\Page::class);
                $model->load($id);
                $title = $model->getTitle();
                $model->delete();
                // display success message
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The page has been deleted.'));
                // go to grid
                $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                    'adminhtml_cmspage_on_delete',
                    ['title' => $title, 'status' => 'success']
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                    'adminhtml_cmspage_on_delete',
                    ['title' => $title, 'status' => 'fail']
                );
                // display error message
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                // go back to edit form
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['page_id' => $id]);
            }
        }
        // display error message
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t find a page to delete.'));
        // go to grid
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

to

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Page;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Delete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Cms::page_delete';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $cmsPageRepository;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface $cmsPageRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface $cmsPageRepository = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->cmsPageRepository = $cmsPageRepository ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Delete action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // check if we know what should be deleted
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id');
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($id) {
            $title = "";
            try {
                // init model and delete
                $model = $this->cmsPageRepository->getById($id);
                $title = $model->getTitle();
                $this->cmsPageRepository->delete($model);
                // display success message
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The page has been deleted.'));
                // go to grid
                $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                    'adminhtml_cmspage_on_delete',
                    ['title' => $title, 'status' => 'success']
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                    'adminhtml_cmspage_on_delete',
                    ['title' => $title, 'status' => 'fail']
                );
                // display error message
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                // go back to edit form
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['page_id' => $id]);
            }
        }
        // display error message
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t find a page to delete.'));
        // go to grid
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your code here

Comment: I guess that magento use this object manager fir backward -compatibility

Comment: @AmitBera I have added the backward compatibility in dependency injection as per Magento2 documentation at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/contributor-guide/backward-compatible-development/#adding-a-constructor-parameter